# Run script on Awesome WM startup

Tags: scripts, startup, awesome, lua

I'm trying to run a script on Awesome WM start after the login screen (not on the `awesome --replace` or `awesome.restart()`).

Does anyone knows the way? No matter is it some kind of `/etc/rc.*` script or the `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua` solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, adding those signals handlers into `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua`:

```lua
awesome.connect_signal(
    'exit',
    function(args)
        awful.util.spawn('touch ~/.awesome-restart')
    end
)

awesome.connect_signal(
    'startup',
    function(args)
        awful.util.spawn('bash -c "rm ~/.awesome-restart || ~/script-to-run-on-startup.sh"')
    end
)
```

Explaining: 
- on the **exit** signal, that performs only on awesome restart we're creating a flag file, that tells to the **startup** signal that this startup is going immediately after the awesome restart
- on the **startup** signal fired we're removing this flag and if it doesn't remove successfully (doesn't exist) - we're running our startup-only script.

PS: Checked - the **exit** signal doesn't fire on `sudo reboot`, so it won't be inappropriately fired on full system restart.